# How to get all variables defined within a Clojure project?

Tags: clojure, namespaces

I am collecting all user defined functions within a project. As a way of testing membership I use:

```
(defn get-var-namespace
  [qualified-var]
  {:pre [(var? qualified-var)]}
  (-> qualified-var meta :ns))

(defn project-name
  "returns a string representation of the root project name.
  this is the same as the directory that the project is located in"
  []
  (last (str/split (System/getProperty "user.dir") #"/")))

(defn get-project-namespaces
  "return all namespaces defined within the project"
  []
  (let [p-name (project-name)]
    (filter (fn [x]
              (let [n (first (str/split (str (ns-name x)) #"\."))]
                (= n p-name))) (all-ns))))

(defn user-defined-var? [project-namespaces var]
  (some #{(get-var-namespace var)} project-namespaces))


(defn namespace-deps
  "returns a map whose keys are user defined functions and vals are sets of
  user defined functions."
  [project-namespaces ns]
  (let [find-vars-in-expr
        (fn [x] (let [nodes (ast/nodes x)
                      top-level (:var (first nodes))
                      non-recursive-deps (remove #{top-level}
                                                 (filter (partial var-has-user-ns project-namespaces)
                                                         (filter some? (map :var nodes))))]
                  {top-level (set non-recursive-deps)}))]
    (dissoc (apply merge-with clojure.set/union
                   (map find-vars-in-expr (jvm/analyze-ns ns))) nil)))
```

as an example

```
clj-smart-test.core> (clojure.pprint/pprint (namespace-deps (get-project-namespaces) *ns*))
{#'clj-smart-test.core/foo
 #{#'clj-smart-test.baz/baz1 #'clj-smart-test.core/bar
   #'clj-smart-test.foo/foo #'clj-smart-test.core/k},
 #'clj-smart-test.core/get-project-namespaces
 #{#'clj-smart-test.core/project-name},
 #'clj-smart-test.core/project-name #{},
 #'clj-smart-test.core/var-has-user-ns
 #{#'clj-smart-test.core/get-var-namespace},
 #'clj-smart-test.core/bar #{},
 #'clj-smart-test.core/f #{},
 #'clj-smart-test.core/get-var-namespace #{},
 #'clj-smart-test.core/namespace-deps
 #{#'clj-smart-test.core/var-has-user-ns},
 #'clj-smart-test.core/k #{}}
nil
```

Are there any corner cases that I need to be aware of? I know that a user could just create an arbitrary namespace in a file so I can't always assume that the directory that a project is created for example `lein new my-project`, which gives `my-project` as the root dir. This version does not catch `defrecord` etc.

Comment: @glts by user defined I mean a variable that was introduced within a project. The example I give using `namespace-deps` you can see that ` #'clj-smart-test.core/var-has-user-ns` calls  `#'clj-smart-test.core/get-var-namespace`. But calls to say `map` or `filter` are ignored.

Comment: which are the undefined vars in the code? I fixed one that was a typo on my part. The return values are of course not in the code as they are other vars in the project that have no impact on the implementation.